# Finding content of tags, removing tags and outputting it into a variable

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Im looking for a way to:

1. Extracting a piece of text from a variable
2. Removing all tags of a certain kind from the extracted text
3. Outputting the result without the certain tag. (example below)

For example, Let's say this is $string:

```
placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text

    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    Lorem ipsum
    <tag2>
    Dolor sit amet
    </tag1>

placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text
```

I want to extract the contents within `<tag1>`, remove all `<tag2>`'s and then output the text back in string, replacing the first example so that it looks like so:

```
placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text

    <tag1>
    Lorem ipsum
    Dolor sit amet
    </tag1>

placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text
```

I have tried using `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_match("/<tag1>(.*?)<\/tag1>/i", $string, $matches);
foreach($matches as $value){
    $code = str_replace("<tag2>", "", $value);
    $string = str_replace($value, $code, $string);
}
```

But that doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Instead of regex, start with a DOM parser like http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this:

```
$string = "
placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text

    <tag1>
    <tag2>
    Lorem ipsum
    <tag2>
    Dolor sit amet
    </tag1>

placeholder text placeholder text
placeholder text placeholder text" ;

preg_match("/<tag1>([^\"]*)<\/tag1>/i", $string, $matches);

$formatted_part = preg_replace("/((<tag2>|<\/tag2>)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+)/", "", $matches[1]);
$new = str_replace($matches[1], $formatted_part, $string);

var_dump($new);
```